# How do I set a variable in a mysql statement with 2 instances of the same table? MYSQL, PHP, PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Been at this for a while... I need to set a variable for o_name and o_duplicated for so I can bind them with a value and save it to a new record.
this is the statement

```
INSERT INTO object (o_id, o_owner, o_material, o_size, o_product, o_name, o_enabled, o_duplicated_from)
        SELECT (SELECT MAX(o1.o_id)+1 FROM object o1), o2.o_owner, o2.o_material, o2.o_size, o2.o_product, o2.o_name, o2.o_enabled, o2.o_duplicated_from  
        FROM object o2 
        LEFT JOIN user ON o2.o_owner = 6 WHERE o_id = 23 AND u_email = 'example@example.com'
```